How to define a MAUI global style for your own class?
I have a (non-XAML) MAUI class for which I want to define global styling:
public class MyClass : Grid, IDisposable
{
    private Label label;

    public MyClass () {}

    public MyClass ( ..., ..., ... ) { ....... }

    public Color TextColor 
    {
        set { label.TextColor = value; }
    }
    ....
}

In Styles.xaml, I have added a local namespace:
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views">

and I added the following entry to Styles.xaml:


<Style TargetType="local:MyClass">
    <Setter Property="local:MyClass.TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Primary}}" />
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="local:MyClass.TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>


I then get the following build error:
XFC0001 Cannot resolve property "TextColor" on type "MyClass (property missing or missing ancestors"

If I remove "local:" or "local:MyClass." from the two property assignments, then I get:
XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui:MyClass"

What am I missing?

You can declare the TextColor as bindable property and then set the style:
public class MyClass : Grid, IDisposable
  {
      private Label label;
      public static readonly BindableProperty TextColorProperty =
BindableProperty.Create("TextColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyClass), Colors.Black);
      public Color TextColor
      {
          get => (Color)GetValue(TextColorProperty);
          set { SetValue(TextColorProperty, value); label.TextColor = value; }
      }
     
  }

For more information, you can read the official document about Bindable properties
